# Continuously play HTML5 Audio while browsing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I wanted to add music on my portfolio, but problem was navigating through site. When someone go from Home to Projects music starts again.

I realized that I need JavaScript. Because I don't want to use AJAX Page Load I created jQuery script that writes elapsed time to cookie `TimeElapsed`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function SetCookie(Value) {
    $.cookie('TimeElapsed', Value, { path: '/' });
  }
  if($.cookie('TimeElapsed') === null || $.cookie('TimeElapsed') === "" || $.cookie('TimeElapsed') === "null" || $.cookie('TimeElapsed') === undefined) {
    $("audio").get(0).play();
    UpdateTime();
  } else {
    $("audio").get(0).play();
    $("audio").get(0).pause();
    $("audio").get(0).currentTime = $.cookie('TimeElapsed');
    $("audio").get(0).play();
    console.log('Start Time: '+$("audio").get(0).currentTime);
    UpdateTime();
  }
  function UpdateTime() {
    $("audio").on("timeupdate", function(event){
      SetCookie(this.currentTime);
    });
  }
})
```

This script works excellent when browsing through Opera and Google Chrome, but when I use Mozilla Firefox or some Android phone browser it returns error and music doesn't play.

Error in Firefox:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
>   or is no longer, usable

On line:

> $("audio").get(0).currentTime = $.cookie('TimeElapsed');

Comment: you could use the **window.onbeforeunload** and **localstorage** to achieve this instead of cookies. :)

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to simply have one page with an iframe pointed to your site and your sound controller.. that way whenever the page changes in the iframe, it doesn't effect the sound controller.

Comment: @toskv Cookie exist and have value when I reload page, but `currentTime` won't set